# Can a steel shield be equipped with wooden spikes?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, shield, special-materials

We found out our party might be fighting vampires. It could be cool if my shield-bashing fighter affixed wooden shield spikes on heavy steel shield. Can this be a thing, RAW?

Comment: I added the [[tag:special-materials]] tag, since the property we’re interested in (especially effective against vampires) is not a real-world property of wood, even though wood is, obviously, a real-world material.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The rules, as written, are completely silent on the subject of what materials are used in the construction of shield spikes. If you want a RAW answer, that’s the best you’ll get: the answer is *undefined*, RAW.

Personally, I always assumed they were metal, but I don’t have any particular problem with allowing them to be wood. Especially if they were some fancy, harder wood, and clearly if you used the *ironwood* spell there would be zero difficulty, from my perspective. Another GM might require some kind of fancier, harder wood, or even require *ironwood*.

The other thing that’s unclear to me is if you can add shield spikes to an already-existing shield. The rules don’t say; I kind of always assumed that a shield and a spiked shield were two separate items and you couldn’t convert from one to the other, but again, that’s not written anywhere. I guess the fact that shield spikes are in the “Extras” section might imply they could be added on later? Anyway, I certainly wouldn’t block a player from doing so if they wanted. But again, that’s not RAW; RAW is just silent.

Comment: There is nothing IRL against this, either. Every forge can add iron spikes to iron shield, why not. Metal spikes to wood shield is even easier. Putting wood on shield would be tricky, but hey, we are talking about a world with alchemical superglue.

Comment: @Mołot not tricky at all. Just weld (forge?) metal screws onto the shield, then screw wooden spikes on. Would be trivial to replace then.

Answer (score 6):

As this [other answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/132319/21153) already explains, there is no *rules as written* for wooden spikes, so you will have to *GM Fiat* a solution there.

But I would like to point out that a [Wooden Stake](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/stake-wooden) is a specific item in the game, and simply using *pointy-wooden-weapons* might not be of any help against vampires.

[Vampire Weaknesses](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/vampire/) says:

> Driving a **wooden stake** through a helpless vampire’s heart instantly slays it (this is a full-round action). However, it returns to life if the stake is removed, unless the head is also severed and anointed with holy water.

There is no mention of other commonly made of wood weapons, such as javelins, arrows or even spears. That said, I believe the weakness to wooden stakes is rooted in [mysticism](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-a-wooden-stake-needed-to-kill-a-vampire-Where-did-the-story-originated), and not an actual weakness against having their heart pierced by wood. So your GM would have to specifically allow that exception to work. Personally, I know I wouldn't let it work, but you sure are welcome to try and I would never try to stop you.

Comment: As a [wooden stake](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/stake-wooden) *is just a sharpened piece of wood* doesn't that mean that any sharpened wood would work?

Comment: @Ben Doesn't work like that. If you break a table's leg and use as a weapon, *that is just a club*, but the game will treat that as an *improvised weapon* instead. If he wants to break an arrow, javelin or spear and treat it as *improvised stakes* that is fine, but that's *GM Fiat* territory.

Comment: Given that (A) attaching spikes to a shield is likely OK, and (B) wooden stakes are defined in the link given as 'just a sharpened piece of wood', how can one posit that attaching a wooden stake to a shield is somehow different to attaching any other pointy bit of whatever you have lying around? If they're crafting this thing they could acquire Wooden Stakes to use instead of just whittling some out of a bit of tree, but it seems a bit arbitrary.

Comment: @Xymist_ Im not sure what you are trying to say, but considering that you are assuming that something *GM Fiat* is "likely OK", I can already tell you that you will see table variation there. There is no specific rule for crafting "wooden spikes", there are no generic rule for attaching a weapon to another, or an item to another. So, we are making a lot of assumptions here that the rules does not cover.